# React Native with visual studio 2015 IDE

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, visual-studio-2015, react-native

Is there a way to use React Native with visual studio 2015?
I'm planing to build a mobile app using this new technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [recent release](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/released-today-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-4-6-asp-net-5-ef-7-previews) added support for React syntax highlighting. But the complete tooling support is not there. You can up-vote it here... https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/10362174-add-react-native-support-to-vs2015